# Excel VBA. How to count isolated number series

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with a column comprising of over 100000 rows of 1's and 0's. I am trying use and excel vba macro to count the number of times the number O occurs in a continuous sequence of 0's. My column of numbers looks something like this (I have placed it in a row for simplicity)

1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1

Thus, the first sequence of 0's starts in second place and there are four consecutive O's. I am trying to develop a macro that counts the number of 0's in the first sequence. Thereafter, once a 1 appears, the macro returns the sequential number in the adjacent column. The Macro will continue until it comes across another 0 and repeats the process. Thus in seventh place it will start counting the number of zeros again from Nil and return the answer 3 in the adjacent column. This process should continue for all 100,000 rows.

Below is my attempt at the macro. The problem is that it returns the total number of zeros from the 100,000 or so rows of data. Please assist me.

Sub Step1CountsNumberZerosInSequence()

' CountsNumberZerosInSequence Macro
' Macro determines the number of zeros ina sequence and returns the value
'

'Step 1: Declare variables
    Dim CloseOutRange As Range
    Dim CloseOutCell As Range
    Dim MaxDays As Integer
    MaxDays = 1

'Step 2: Define the Target Range
    Set CloseOutRange = Range("AY10:AY100000")

'Step 3: Start looping through the range
    For Each CloseOutCell In CloseOutRange

'Step 4: Do something with each cell
    If CloseOutCell.Value = 0 Then
    MaxDays = MaxDays + 1
    End If

'Step 5: Get the next cell in the range
    Next CloseOutCell

'Step 6: Else stop and provide the maximum number
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = MaxDays

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you have to insert an `ElseIf` in Step 4, like

```
'Step 4: Do something with each cell 
If CloseOutCell.Value = 0 Then 
    MaxDays = MaxDays + 1 
ElseIf CloseOutCell.Value = 1 Then
    MaxDays = 0
End If
```

Edit: This will return 0 at the end of your sequence. If you want to "keep" the last 0-count, you could use a temp-Variable, for example:

```
Dim temp = 0 as Integer
If CloseOutCell.Value = 0 Then 
    MaxDays = MaxDays + 1
    temp = MaxDays 
ElseIf CloseOutCell.Value = 1 Then
    MaxDays = 0
End If
Return temp
```